# Javascript fadeIn/fadeOut "stacking"

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

Trying to get a simple fadeIn/fadeOut work the way I want, basically, my problem is that it won't overwrite, or stop the function, if I've hovered over another element that triggers the action, and it kind puts it in a queue, and will play all the animations, even after my mouse is not even near the elements. I would like it to not let the function trigger again, unless the fadeout has been finished.

```
$("p").hover(
function() 
{
    $(document.getElementById('Bottom_Menu')).fadeIn(200);
},
function() 
{
    $(document.getElementById('Bottom_Menu')).fadeOut(350);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quickly answer your question, you can use `stop()`.

```
$("#Bottom_Menu").stop().fadeTo(200, 1);
```

You don't have to use `document.getElementById`; instead, just use #id. For classes, use .class. It's all built in to jQuery. :)

**UPDATE**

I'm now using `fadeTo` instead of `fadeIn`, because `fadeIn` only works when display is none. So if we're canceling the previous animation with `stop()`, we need to use `fadeTo`, since the display may not be none. (When you use `fadeOut`, it fades out the element, and when complete, it sets the element's display to none, which hides the element.)

**Notes:**

The second property of `fadeTo` is opacity.
`fadeTo`, like `fadeIn`, still automatically changes the display property so the element is visible.

Comment: Thank you, it somewhat gives what I want :P

Comment: @FireyFly If you need more help so it gives what you *really* want, don't refrain from asking! :)

Comment: Well, basically, i would like it to overwrite the previous animation, instead of stopping it, because if i am moving my mouse between buttons, this way it just goes half opaque, and then vanishes if i move my mouse off of it, so basically it just pauses the animation, best would be to overwrite the previous one.

Comment: @FireyFly I'm having trouble understanding you. I've made an edit to my post. See if that helps.

Comment: Sorry if i was hard to understand, but you nailed it, thank you so much! perfect! :x

Answer (score 1):

`$("#Bottom_Menu").clearQueue();`

clears all pending animations/operations to do on this element

Comment: Thank you too, this is useful too!